# How to pass a range to Enum.filter in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to pass a range to Elixir's `Enum.filter`.  For e.g.

This works

```
[1,2,3,4,5] |> Enum.filter(&rem(&1,2)==0) #=> [2,4]
```

But this doesn't

```
[1..10] |> Enum.filter(&rem(&1,2)==0) #=> bad argument in arithmetic...
```

I have a list containing a range that I would like to pass to filter.  Eg.

```
[1..10, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap it in `[]`.

```
iex(1)> 1..10 |> Enum.filter(&rem(&1,2)==0)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

`[1..10]` is a list of length 1 with the first element equal to the range `1..10`.

---

To filter a list containing numbers and ranges, I would use `Enum.flat_map` like this:

```
iex(2)> [1..10, 2, 3] |> Enum.flat_map(fn
...(2)>   n when is_number(n) -> if rem(n, 2) == 0, do: [n], else: []
...(2)>   enum -> Enum.filter(enum, &rem(&1, 2) == 0)
...(2)> end)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2]
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But how do I then pass a list to filter that has a range element?  e.g. here is my list `list = [1..10, 2 , 3]` that I would like to filter as above.

Comment: You can either convert that to a flat list using `Enum.to_list(1..10) ++ [2, 3]` and pass that, or switch to `Enum.flat_map` and inside that run `Enum.filter` if the item is a range otherwise return `[]` or `[x]` if the item is a number.

Comment: I've added an implementation of the second method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use parentheses when creating a range for readability, just use `()`.

```
(1..10) |> Enum.filter(&rem(&1,2)==0)
```

In your example the most readable solution is:

```
# declare anonymous function for checking is number even
is_even = &rem(&1,2) == 0
(1..10) |> Enum.filter(&is_even.(&1))
```

Comment: In the second one you can just do `|> Enum.filter(is_even)`. :)

Comment: @Dogbert: Would appreciate if you could throw in pointers on how it works without `&, &1` in the second one. I mean when do I need `&` and when I don't?

Comment: @Bala `Enum.filter` requires an anonymous function, i.e. `fn ... end`. The `&` syntax is used to convert a module's function into an anonymous function. In this case `is_even` is already an anonymous function. `&is_even.(&1)` is redundant and is equivalent to just `is_even`.

Comment: Though, it works only when anonymous function takes `only one` argument. You can't apply this rule when using fn with more than one argument regardless of using pipe operator or not.

Comment: @PatNowak not sure what you mean by anonymous function taking only one argument: `double = fn k, v -> v * 2 end; :maps.map(double, %{1 => 2, 3 => 4}) #=> %{1 => 4, 3 => 8}`.

Comment: Consider this example: you have `add = fn elem, x -> elem + x end` and you want to create new `list` from applying this func on `1..10`, which was used before. You want to add `1` or anything else to each of element of the range. You can't do `(1..10) |> Enum.map(add.(1))`, but you have to call it explicitly `(1..10) |> Enum.map(&add.(&1, 1))`.

Comment: @PatNowak Ah yeah, that's partial application and does require using the `&` syntax even if you have anonymous functions. Note that this does work: `add = fn x -> fn y -> x + y end end; (1..5) |> Enum.map(add.(1)) #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.